# How do I use an Outlook macro to connect to an excel file that's already open?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-automation

I'm trying to write a Macro that will refer out to a file I use to track credits(I call it Master6 below). In the code excerpt below I try to do some initial testing like, see if excel is even running, or if the Master6 file is already open. I'm able to get past the line of code where it correctly determines that the Master6 file is open, but then I get a Run Time error 9 at the part where it says "Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks(xExcelFile)". At this line of code I'm trying to specify what xWb(aka my workbook) should be.

Note that I originally asked this question and I got one response saying, *"You need to make sure that both applications are run under the same security context (run as admin or same user). There is no way to access/automate application which is run under a different security context."* I don't know how to determine what security context a file is open under/how to make it match security contexts, even though I tried researching it.

```
Sub SearchQueryForCredits()

'Declare some initial variables
    Dim xExcelFile As String
    Dim xExcelApp As excel.Application
    Dim xWb As excel.Workbook
    Dim xWs As excel.Worksheet
    Dim xExcelRange As excel.Range
    Dim Cell As Range

    xExcelFile = "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Desktop Credits\MASTER6.xlsm"
    
    
    
    'initiate Excel object...Therefore, you can use this to test if there is an Excel instance already open on your machine.
On Error Resume Next
Set ExApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If ExApp Is Nothing Then Set ExApp = New excel.Application
    

'LOGIC TO TELL IF THE MASTER6 FILE IS ALREADY OPEN
    Dim Ret
    Ret = IsWorkBookOpen(xExcelFile)

'What to do if the Master6 file is open
    If Ret = True Then
            Set xExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
                If Err <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "MASTER6 is not running"
                Else
                MsgBox "MASTER6 is running"
                End If

            Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks(xExcelFile) <---- THIS IS WHERE I GET "RUN TIME ERROR '9': SUBSCRIPT OUT OF RANGE
            Set xWs = xWb.Sheets("Query Run")
            Set xExcelRange = xWs.Range("I:I")

            
            
'What to do if the Master6 file is NOT open
    Else.......'rest of code i don't think is relevant to this issue
```

Also, my code above uses the function below in order to tell if my Master6 file is open.

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is your goal of connecting to the excel file?

Answer (score 1):

If Excel is run under a different security context your VBA macro will not find the process in the code, so the following code:

```
Set xExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

Will not be successful. You will have to create a new Excel instance and open the file anew.

```
' Start Excel and get Application object.
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oXL.Visible = True
```

Read more about that in the [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-basic) article.

Also you may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) if you deal with open XML documents only.